# Python split data from socket

Tags: python, sockets, split

I'm trying to figure out how to split data received from a socket. I have the sockets working and I can get the data correctly but I now want to split the data retrieved and obtain the last string. Here is what I'm trying(data is the data received from the socket)

```
split = data.split(' ')
print split
print split[-1]
```

But when I try it it wont work for some reason. Like lets say I have the string received as "test test1"
I want to get test1.

Comment: Does split contain anything at all? Do you have binary data in `data`? Your example should work as long as it can be split correctly (assumes the string not to be zero etc.)

Comment: I'm sending the string "test test1". No binary or anything just that string.

Comment: When you say it "won't work": what does happen? Do you get an error? What shows up on screen?

Comment: Well I'm attempting to preform os.chdir(split[-1])
But I get the error sh: chdir/ not found

Comment: If you just do `print split[-1]`, what does it show?

Comment: @AustinM You must begin to give a name to the result of `data.split(' ')` that ought to be not the name of a built-in function ! Otherwise, after the first instruction `split = data.split(' ') ` , split is no more the function. Secondly, what does data contain ? did you print it to see ?

Comment: Here is the thing. I have to search for multiple commands. So the client sends the command "chdir" + dir(which is a raw input). Then the server receives it and looks to see if it's "chdir". If it is, then it does os.chdir(split[-1])

Comment: @AustinM: OK. But the key is to work out what's ending up in split[-1]. So do a `print` and see what it shows.

Comment: If I print that it prints what I want it to. But the problem is I need to search through the data received and look for "chdir" and if that is true then do something.

Comment: @AustinM what-does-data-contain ?

Comment: `if split[0] == "chdir": os.chdir(split[1])`? I'm not following which bit you're having trouble with here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
>>> data = "chdir /"
>>> a = data.split(" ")
>>> a
['chdir', '/']
>>> a[-1]
'/'
```

This appears to be what you're looking for. The reason your code doesn't work likely lies with the exact content of `data`.

Note that using `.split(" ")` is slightly different than `.split()` when you have multiple spaces in the original string. See for example:

```
>>> "chdir /".split(" ")
['chdir', '/']
>>> "chdir  /".split(" ")
['chdir', '', '/']
>>> "chdir  /".split()
['chdir', '/']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that it is bad practice to use the names of common library functions to name objects in your own code.

Sometimes it creates errors, but it always creates confusion.

Comment: The word 'variable' is ambiguous in Python. In your sentence it means: "the references to which names are binded, and that contain the adresses of the objects". But that is out of subject. BTW, even the word 'reference' is not very good because it is not the same as in C++ for example.